# Functional Inequality given $s\cdot f(t)+t\cdot f(s)\leq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality

Question:
For all continuous $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\ $ and $\forall s,t \in [0,1]$ that satisfies: $$s\cdot f(t)+t\cdot f(s) \le 2$$ **a)** Prove that: $$\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx \le {\pi/2}.$$
**b)** How many function $f(x)$ exists that satisfies the equality in **a**?

Comment: It is tight for $f(x)=\dfrac{2}{1+x^2}$, so you might try to prove that $f(x) \leq \dfrac{2}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: @Aravind: however, that function does not fulfill the initial constraint.

Comment: Right; I made a mistake. The function $g(x)=\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}$ satisfies the constraints, but then is not tight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $s=\sin\left(\frac{\pi\theta}{2}\right)$ and $t=\cos\left(\frac{\pi\theta}{2}\right)$. We have:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi\theta}{2}\right)\cdot f\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi\theta}{2}\right)\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi\theta}{2}\right)\cdot f\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi\theta}{2}\right)\right)\,d\theta \leq 2\tag{1}$$
but the LHS of $(1)$ is just:
$$ \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(u)\, f(\sin u)\,du = \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx \tag{2} $$
and the claim is proved. $f(x)=2\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $f(x)=2\sqrt{x(2-x)}$ are extremal functions.

Comment: Thanks for the only true assumed solution ,but I wonder how did you find the **extrermal** functions, are there just these two functions?

Comment: @MasM: I am not sure they are the only extremal functions, I just found them by looking at simple rational function with integral $\frac{\pi}{2}$ over $[0,1]$ and checking that they fulfill the initial constraint on $s,t$.

Comment: well, so I add part **b)** to the question, it seems that it may be more challenging